# Where do you buy Elite Dangerous for Mac?

Tags: macos, elite-dangerous

In the Frontier Store, https://www.frontierstore.net/games/elite-dangerous-cat.html, I can see Elite for Mac, but no other version for Mac. There's Elite Dangerous and Elite Dangerous Deluxe, but none of those list Mac as supported.

How do I get Elite Dangerous for Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steam store has Elite Dangerous aswell, and Horizons. They can be played on the Mac, not sure about the elitedangerous website, but if steam sells it for mac, you should get it over there too.

Comment: They can't both be played on a Mac though.  It even shows on Steam that ED is supported on Mac, ED:H isn't.

Comment: My apologies, I thought they would both work on a Mac.

Answer (score 3):

Elite Dangerous is Mac supported, however some other titles such as Elite Dangerous: Horizons / Arena are not.    The Elite Dangerous Deluxe package available from the Frontier website includes Horizons, and so is not Mac supported.

The official Frontier site states that this is because the necessary shaders / OpenGL support are not available yet on the Mac.

https://support.frontier.co.uk/kb/faq.php?id=228

> Sadly, neither the OS X OpenGL nor Apple's Metal API support the required compute shaders and the other possibilities that we have explored simply don’t allow us the performance that Elite Dangerous: Horizons requires.